# How do you enforce a common signature across a collection of functions?

Tags: python

I have a class with with dozens of "similar" methods. They all should implement the same signature and return type, input validation is fairly similar, but they are otherwise independent.

These can act as an example:

```
def calculate_mass(self, relativistic:bool=False, tol=0.001, verbose:int=0)->pd.Series:
    ... 
    return ans 

...

def calculate_energy(self, relativistic:bool=False, tol=0.001, verbose:int=0)->pd.Series:
    ... 
    return ans 

# etc.
```

Is there a neat way to enforce a common signature across these methods? It'd be great to also build in some input validation without copying code.

Comment: What do you mean by "enforce"?

Comment: In this specific example you could have a single `calculate()` function with an additional argument of the type of thing you are calculating.

Comment: By enforce I mean, I want to make sure no developer (me?) forgets to implement a relativistic = True/False part of the code, etc...

Comment: A function signature is merely a list of parameters a function accepts in its `def` statement, There no way to enforce code to be written that uses them. If the parameters have type hints then a third-party module can do some static type-checking, but again that has no bearing on whether or how they're used by the function's code. The point being that what you want done can't be accomplished by enforcing a common signature.

Comment: I'm in the headspace of Metaclasses and abstract methods... where you can enforce that all subclasses must implement a given method.